# Return filenames from class.uploader.php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, return, uploader

I've been trying everything, and it's starting to get on my nerves. I'm still trying to learn the ropes within PHP, so please bear with me.

I'm using the class.uploader.php to upload files to my server. It works as it should, but I want to *just* return the uploaded file(s) when the upload is complete. This is where I'm stuck.

This is my code;

```
<?php
include('assets/plugins/filer/php/class.uploader.php');

$uploader = new Uploader();
$data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
    'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
    'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
    'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
    'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
    'uploadDir' => 'upload/', //Upload directory {String}
    'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
    'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
    'replace' => false, //Replace the file if it already exists  {Boolean}
));

if($data['isComplete']){

    $info = $data['data'];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($info);
    echo '</pre>';
}

if($data['hasErrors']){
    $errors = $data['errors'];
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

When upload completes, this is what it returns;

```
Array
(
[files] => Array
    (
        [0] => upload/  - TEST - #01.wav
        [1] => upload/  - TEST - #02.wav
    )

[metas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => Wed, 22 Feb 2017 14:03:42 +0100
                [extension] => wav
                [file] => upload/  - TEST - #01.wav
                [name] =>   - TEST - #01.wav
                [old_name] =>   - TEST - #01.wav
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 1244204
                [size2] => 1.19 MB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => audio
                        [1] => wav
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => Wed, 22 Feb 2017 14:03:42 +0100
                [extension] => wav
                [file] => upload/  - TEST - #02.wav
                [name] =>   - TEST - #02.wav
                [old_name] =>   - TEST - #02.wav
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 1677356
                [size2] => 1.60 MB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => audio
                        [1] => wav
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

What I want to return is something like this;

```
Upload complete.
The following files has been uploaded:
- TEST - #02.wav
- TEST - #02.wav
```

Been trying for a while now, but I can't figure it out. Anyone care to help out? I've tried "echo $_FILES['files']", but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Loop through `$data['data']['metas']` with the `for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++)` function and count all array values. Then you get the values like: `$data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]`

Comment: I'll give that a try!

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I'm trying to get each filename on a seperate line, now all filenames are displayed on one line. How can I do that?

Comment: See my answer below :-). You can do something with the breakline code in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the `$data['data']['metas']` with the `for()` function. Like example given below:

```
...
Upload complete.
The following files has been uploaded:

<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++)
{
    echo "- ".$data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]."<br />";
}
?>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Secondly, I'm trying to upload these files to FTP. I got that working, but it just uploads ONE of those files I'm uploading if I have multiple.

I'm trying to use this;
    $files-to-upload = $data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"];

Then it just uploads one of those files I just uploaded to my webserver. How can I upload all files? In my earlier script I had $filnavn = $_FILES['upl']['name']; and that worked.... @C0dekid